# How to show the Bluetooth Le Device connected/Disconnected status constantly

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to develop an application where the user can know the status of his/her Bluetooth Le device once he/she launches the app and the connection status is updated in text view in Home Fragment.I have tried to implement it by sending Broadcast from Ble service and catching it in onResume of Home fragment and subsequently updating it in status text view. The status does gets updated but if I change the fragment and come back to the home fragment the text view to show the status gets blank although the Bluetooth Le device is connected.How can I resolve this problem so that the status shows connected all through out if the device is connected and disconnected if it is disconnected?

Any Kind of guidance will be highly appreciated.

here are the code segments I have used to implement the above

In **Bleservice.java**

```
 private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        String intentAction;

        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
            mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;


            broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");

            // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
            Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                    mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());

        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
            mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
            Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
            broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
        }
    }

 private void broadcastUpdate(final String action) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

**In HomeFragment.java**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment 
{
    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if (Bleservice.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                mConnected = true;
                updateConnectionState(R.string.connected);


            } else if (Bleservice.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                mConnected = false;
                updateConnectionState(R.string.disconnected);


            }
        }


    };
    getActivity().registerReceiver(mReceiver,makeGattUpdateIntentFilter());

}

private void updateConnectionState(final int resourceId) {
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            tv_connected_disconnected.setText(resourceId);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}

 private static IntentFilter makeGattUpdateIntentFilter() {
    final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Bleservice.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED);
    intentFilter.addAction(Bleservice.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
    return intentFilter;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Connect to your BleService by bindService. Check out example with Activity and Service.

```
private BleService mBluetoothLeService;
private boolean isConnected;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Intent bindIntent = new Intent(this, BleService.class);
    startService(bindIntent);
    bindService(bindIntent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    registerServiceReceiver(); //register here your mGattCallback that get actions from BleService
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    unbindService(mServiceConnection);
    mBluetoothLeService = null;
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver);
}
```

In method bindService you need to pass a ServiceConnection that manage Service Lifecycle.

```
// Code to manage Service lifecycle.
private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder service) {

        mBluetoothLeService = ((BleService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
        isConnected = (mBluetoothLeService.getConnectionState() != BleService.STATE_CONNECTED) 

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        mBluetoothLeService = null;
    }
};
```

In Service you need to declare Binder.

```
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public BleService getService() {
        return BleService.this;
    }
}


public int getConnectionState() {
    return mConnectionState;
}
```

So now, after binding to BleService, you can get a connection state.